# Verilog ERROR:Xst:528: Multi-source signal; this signal is connected to multiple drivers

Tags: syntax-error, verilog, processor

This is the execution block of a processor. Most of the code is included only for reference.

```
module Execution_Block(A, B, data_in, op_dec, flag_ex, ans_ex, data_out,
                mem_en_dec, mem_rw_dec, mem_mux_sel_dec, RW_dec, clk, reset,
                B_Bypass, mem_en_ex, mem_rw_ex, mem_mux_sel_ex, RW_ex);

         //INPUTS
         input [7:0] A, B, data_in;
         input clk, reset, mem_en_dec, mem_rw_dec, mem_mux_sel_dec;
         input [4:0] RW_dec;
         input [4:0] op_dec;

         //OUTPUTS
         output [3:0] flag_ex;
         output reg mem_en_ex, mem_rw_ex, mem_mux_sel_ex;
         output reg [7:0] B_Bypass, ans_ex, data_out;
         output reg [4:0] RW_ex; 

         //WIRES
         wire [7:0] ans_temp, data_out_buff;
         wire [7:0] W0, W1,W2, W3, W4, W5, W6, W7, W8, W9, W10, W11, W12,                                W13, W14, W15, W16, W17, W18, W19, W20,
         W21, W22, W23, W24, W25, W26, W27, W28;
         wire P;
         wire [3:0]flag_temp;
         wire [3:0]flag_hold_prev;

        //ALU
        assign W0  = (op_dec == 5'b00000) ? (A+B)       : W1;       //ADD
        assign W1  = (op_dec == 5'b00001) ? (A+(~B+1))  : W2;       //SUB
        assign W2  = (op_dec == 5'b00010) ? (B)         : W3;       //MOV
        assign W3  = (op_dec == 5'b00100) ? (A&B)       : W4;       //AND
        assign W4  = (op_dec == 5'b00101) ? (A|B)          : W5;        //OR
        assign W5  = (op_dec == 5'b00110) ? (A^B)       : W6;       //XOR
        assign W6  = (op_dec == 5'b00111) ? (~B)        : W7;       //NOR
        assign W7  = (op_dec == 5'b01000) ? (A+B)       : W8;       //ADI
        assign W8  = (op_dec == 5'b01001) ? (A+(~B+1))  : W9;       //SBI
        assign W9  = (op_dec == 5'b01010) ? (B)         : W10;  //NVI
        assign W10 = (op_dec == 5'b01100) ? (A&B)      : W11;   //ANI
        assign W11 = (op_dec == 5'b01101) ? (A|B)      : W12;   //ORI
        assign W12 = (op_dec == 5'b01110) ? (A^B)      : W13;   //XRI
        assign W13 = (op_dec == 5'b01111) ? (~B)        : W14;  //NTI
        assign W14 = (op_dec == 5'b10000) ? (ans_temp)  : W15;  //RET
        assign W15 = (op_dec == 5'b10001) ? (ans_temp)  : W16;  //HLT
        assign W16 = (op_dec == 5'b10100) ? (A)         : W17;  //LD
        assign W17 = (op_dec == 5'b10101) ? (A)         : W18;  //ST
        assign W18 = (op_dec == 5'b10110) ? (data_in)   : W19;  //IN
        assign W19 = (op_dec == 5'b00111) ? (ans_temp)  : W20;  //OUT
        assign W20 = (op_dec == 5'b11000) ? (ans_temp)  : W21;  //JMP
        assign W21 = (op_dec == 5'b11001) ? (A<<B)      : W22;  //LS
        assign W22 = (op_dec == 5'b11011) ? (A>>B)      : W23;  //RS
        assign W23 = (op_dec == 5'b11011) ? 
                ((A[2:0]==3'b000) ? B : 
                ((A[2:0]==3'b001) ? {B[7], B[7:1]} : 
                ((A[2:0]==3'b010) ? {B[7], B[7],  B[7:2]} : 
                ((A[2:0]==3'b011) ? {B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7:3]} : 
                ((A[2:0]==3'b100) ? {B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7:4]} : 
                ((A[2:0]==3'b101) ? {B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7:5]} : 
                ((A[2:0]==3'b110) ? {B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7:6]} : 
                ((A[2:0]==3'b111) ? {B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7], B[7]}: 0)))))))) : W24;  //RSA

        assign W24 = (op_dec == 5'b11100) ? (ans_temp)  : W25;          //JC
        assign W25 = (op_dec == 5'b11101) ? (ans_temp)  : W26;      //JNC
        assign W26 = (op_dec == 5'b11110) ? (ans_temp)  : W27;          //JZ
        assign W27 = (op_dec == 5'b11111) ? (ans_temp)  : W28;      //JNZ
        assign W28 = 8'b00000000;

        //ANSWER TEMP
        assign ans_temp = ((op_dec == 5'b00000) ? W0 :              //ADD
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00001) ? W1 :                    //SUB
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00010) ? W2 :                    //MOV
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00100) ? W3 :                    //AND
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00101) ? W4 :                    //OR
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00110) ? W5 :                    //XOR
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00111) ? W6 :                    //NOT
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01000) ? W7 :                    //ADI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01001) ? W8 :                    //SBI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01010) ? W9 :                    //MVI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01100) ? W10 :                   //ANI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01101) ? W11 :                   //ORI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01110) ? W12 :                   //XRI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01111) ? W13 :                   //NTI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10000) ? W14 :                   //RET
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10001) ? W15 :                   //HLT
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10100) ? W16 :                   //LD
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10101) ? W17 :                   //ST
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10110) ? W18 :                   //IN
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10111) ? W19 :                   //OUT
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11000) ? W20 :                   //JMP
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11001) ? W21 :                   //LS
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11010) ? W22 :                   //RS
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11011) ? W23 :                   //RSA
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11100) ? W24 :                   //JC
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11101) ? W25 :                   //JNC
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11110) ? W26 :                   //JZ
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11111) ? W27 : W28))))))))))))))))))))))))))));              //JNZ

    //FLAGS
    //CARRY FLAG                    
    assign flag_temp[0] = (A[7]&B[7])|| (A[6]&B[6])|| (A[5]&B[5])|| (A[4]&B[4])|| 
                         (A[3]&B[3])|| (A[2]&B[2])|| (A[1]&B[1])|| (A[0]&B[0]);

  //ZERO FLAG
  assign flag_temp[1] = (ans_temp)? 1 : 0;

  //OVERFLOW FLAG
  assign flag_temp[2] = (A[7]&B[7]) ^ (A[6]&B[6]);

 //PARITY FLAG
 //PARITY GENERATOR
 assign P = ans_temp[7] ^ ans_temp[6] ^ ans_temp[5] ^ ans_temp[4] ^ 
          ans_temp[3] ^ ans_temp[2] ^ ans_temp[1] ^ ans_temp[0];

 //PARITY CHECKER             
 assign flag_temp[3] = ans_temp[7] ^ ans_temp[6] ^ ans_temp[5] ^ ans_temp[4] ^ 
                         ans_temp[3] ^ ans_temp[2] ^ ans_temp[1] ^ ans_temp[0] ^ P;
```

> There is an error of Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit (Execution_Block) on signal (flag_ex) this signal is connected to multiple drivers.

```
//ALL FLAGS AFFECTED: flag_temp[3:0]         
//PARITY AND ZERO AFFECTED, RESET OTHER FLAGS: {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0}      
//RESET ALL FLAGS: 4'b0000          
//HOLD PREVIOUS FLAG: flag_hold_prev    


assign flag_temp= ((op_dec == 5'b00000) ? flag_temp[3:0] :          //ADD
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00001) ? flag_temp[3:0] :        //SUB
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00010) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                          //MOV
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00100) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                          //AND
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00101) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                          //OR
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00110) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                          //XOR
                    ((op_dec == 5'b00111) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                          //NOT
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01000) ? flag_temp[3:0] :                            //ADI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01001) ? flag_temp[3:0] :                            //SBI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01010) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                          //MVI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01100) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                      //ANI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01101) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                      //ORI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01110) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                      //XRI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b01111) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                      //NTI
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10000) ? 4'b0000 :                       //RET
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10001) ? 4'b0000 :                       //HLT
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10100) ? flag_hold_prev :                        //LD
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10101) ? flag_hold_prev :                        //ST
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10110) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                      //IN
                    ((op_dec == 5'b10111) ? flag_hold_prev :                        //OUT
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11000) ? flag_hold_prev :                        //JMP
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11001) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                      //LS
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11010) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                      //RS
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11011) ? {flag_temp[3], 1'b0, flag_temp[1], 1'b0} :                      //RSA
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11100) ? flag_hold_prev :                        //JC
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11101) ? flag_hold_prev :                        //JNC
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11110) ? flag_hold_prev :                        //JZ
                    ((op_dec == 5'b11111) ? flag_hold_prev : W28))))))))))))))))))))))))))));               //JNZ

assign flag_ex = flag_temp;
assign flag_hold_prev = flag_ex;
```

> Even though flag_ex is assigned only once.

```
assign data_out_buff = (op_dec == 5'b10111) ? A : W28;

//REGISTER
always@(posedge clk)
begin
if(reset == 1'b1)                               //RESET SIGNAL IS ON
    begin
            ans_ex <= 8'b00000000;
            data_out <= 8'b00000000;
            mem_en_ex <= 1'b0;
            mem_rw_ex <=    1'b0;
            mem_mux_sel_ex <= 1'b0;
            RW_ex <= 5'b00000;
            B_Bypass <= 8'b00000000;
    end
else                                                //RESET SIGNAL IS OFF
    begin
            ans_ex <= ans_temp;
            data_out <= data_out_buff;
            mem_en_ex <= mem_en_dec;
            mem_rw_ex <=    mem_rw_dec;
            mem_mux_sel_ex <= mem_mux_sel_dec;
            RW_ex <= RW_dec;
            B_Bypass <= B;
    end
   end  
   endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

flag_temp is being assigned in two separate assign statements. Once the individual bits are being assigned and next time the whole bus. This will cause problems with the synthesizer.

Probably you are seeing this error because flag_temp has multiple drivers and that in turn is assigned to flag_ex.

```
//FLAGS
    //CARRY FLAG
    assign flag_temp[0] = (A[7]&B[7])|| (A[6]&B[6])|| (A[5]&B[5])|| (A[4]&B[4])||
                         (A[3]&B[3])|| (A[2]&B[2])|| (A[1]&B[1])|| (A[0]&B[0]);

  //ZERO FLAG
  assign flag_temp[1] = (ans_temp)? 1 : 0;

  //OVERFLOW FLAG
  assign flag_temp[2] = (A[7]&B[7]) ^ (A[6]&B[6]);

 //PARITY FLAG
 //PARITY GENERATOR
 assign P = ans_temp[7] ^ ans_temp[6] ^ ans_temp[5] ^ ans_temp[4] ^
          ans_temp[3] ^ ans_temp[2] ^ ans_temp[1] ^ ans_temp[0];

 //PARITY CHECKER
 assign flag_temp[3] = ans_temp[7] ^ ans_temp[6] ^ ans_temp[5] ^ ans_temp[4] ^
                         ans_temp[3] ^ ans_temp[2] ^ ans_temp[1] ^ ans_temp[0] ^ P;
```

2ns instance .

```
assign flag_temp= ((op_dec == 5'b00000) ? fl ....
```

Comment: Thanks. I replaced assign flag_temp= ((op_dec == 5'b00000) ? fl .... with assign flag_ex= ((op_dec == 5'b00000) ? fl .... it solved the errors in the code but now the waveforms are incorrect an ans_ex, flag_ex don't propogate properly.

Comment: added  assign flag_ex= ((op_dec ==  and removed //assign flag_ex = flag_temp; ans_ex and flag_ex seems to work/propogate after reset , what exactly is not propagating properly ? What is the expected behaviors and what is the current behavior ?